# Use newest Qt5 serialport library in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

Is it possible for me to use the newest QSerialPort family (like the one from Qt5.3.2) in Qt4?
I tried to download the Qt5.3.2's source code and added the QSerialPort files to my projects. I modified some of the includes to eliminate including error. But it doesn't seem to work at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and I've done that before.

---

### [Setup]

1. [**Download the source code of QSerialPort (not from Qt 5)**](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/archive-tarball/stable)
2. Unpack it and extract the folder `qt-qtserialport`
3. Run **QtCreator** and open the “**qtserialport.pro**” project file
4. get to `Projects`(on the left vertical panel) -> `(Your Kit)` -> `Build` -> `Build Steps`
5. Cancel the selection of `Shadow build` (optional)
6. add a new make “Build Step” and write to the “Make arguments” the install target

As a result, the `QtSerialPort` library will be automatically compiled and installed into the desired Qt instance (according to the selected Kit).

### [Usage]

1. In your project file add `CONFIG += serialport`
2. Now you may include the headers.

---

Ref.: http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort

P.S. If you have problems in setting build steps, check [**the document**](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-build-settings.html).

Comment: If I have two different qt version. say 4.8 and 5.3, how could I set it so that only the 4.8 is added with the serialport library? I am using QCreator.

Comment: Or is it possible to add all the source code into my own porject instead of building it into the Qt's directory.

Comment: @Nyaruko If you just want to use source code only, you can try [`QExtSerialPort`](https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) instead. It's easier to use and provide the equivalent functionality. Just download the source code (`.h` and `.cpp` and add to your project)

Comment: @Nyaruko As for your first question, you can build it specifically to the Qt 4.8's folder.

Comment: @Tay2510 Hey. I am using QExtSerialPort library in my project but facing a problem. Can you have a look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367412/qmetaobjectconnectslotsbyname-no-matching-signal-for-on-pushbutton-clicked?noredirect=1#comment73805072_43367412)

Comment: @Tay2510 I didnt get the step 6. What do you mean by `write to the “Make arguments” the install target`