# QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_clicked()

Tags: qt

I am using QT4.8. I am wiriting my application for a embedded linux device. I used a `pushButton` and this is how I am using it:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  ui->label->setText("Hello World");
}
```

As QT4.8 do not have QSerialPort support so I am using QExtSerialPort library. For this I have included below line in .pro file:

```
include(/home/meif/qextserialport/src/qextserialport.pri)
```

After including this, I was able to use serial port library in my project. So when I run the application on my target device, it gave me this warning:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_clicked()
```

When I excluded QExtSerialPort from my project, it worked fine. How come these two are clashing.? I have not even changed any name for puchButton. What could be the error. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to manually re-run qmake?

Comment: @ni1ight Do you mean by right clicking on project and selecing run qmake.?

Comment: yes, or build -> run qmake (if you are working in the QtCreator) if I remember it properly

Comment: @ni1ight Yes I did run qmake but it didnt resolve the issue.

Comment: How did you create the slot? Did you use "go to slot" in fhe form editor? Maybe try to create it once again.

Comment: @ni1ight yes I used go to slot in the form editor. I will try it once again as you said

Comment: @SAndrew I come here to answer your summon. This problem seems very familiar to me, although it's been years. Could you provide the complete project file (.pro)?

Comment: @Tay2510 I have attached a screenshot of .pro file in my question.

Comment: @SAndrew What kind of functions in `QExtSerialPort` did you use? Or did you just include the project file?

Comment: @Tay2510 `QExtSerialPort` is serial port library which works exactly like QSerialPort library. I am using its normal function like Serial->Open or Serial->Write. But thats not the point. The point is if I do not use any functions and just include library, it gives error. I am including its .pri file which automatically includes its header and source files.